# Django 3: Passing slug in URLs to views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-3.0

I'm trying out Django for a webshop, I'm following the instructions of a book(Django 3 by example), but there seem to be something missing.

I have tested if return to home in def product_list seen in views.py, so I believe the problem is in the "if category_slug:" condition or it is not receiving the slug.

In main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

In app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'), 
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='products_list_by_category'), 
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

In views.py:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=False):
        category = None
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        
        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
            products = products.filter(category=category)
            return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})
```

Comment: what did you try and what is not working like you want?

Comment: Show us how you pass the slug into template

Comment: I haven't dealt with passing slug before but I thought I did it here 
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='products_list_by_category'),
as seen in urlpatterns

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in `url_patterns`

```
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='products_list_by_category'),
```

Comment: Thanks there is much going on that need to read into, it did not work but it didn't give me a error either. I will look into it and come back if this could work :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

[Source](https://djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django/)

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing?
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='products_list_by_category'),

though you have as_view() I cant really get it to work, but I have an idea what I can try out.